# Argmin of a sum function - optimization of min search

Tags: matlab, optimization

I'm trying to write the following optimization problem in Matlab:

> g = argmin Σ<sub>k=1,2,3</sub> ( (v<sub>k</sub> - c<sub>1</sub>) - g·(D<sub>k</sub> - c<sub>2</sub>) )²
>
> c<sub>1</sub> and c<sub>2</sub> are constants. v<sub>k</sub> and D<sub>k</sub> are vectors. g has to be positive.

I have realized that MATLAB has a built in function [fminsearch](http://nl.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/fminsearch.html) which should be able to perform the task, however I don't know how to include the sum over all `k` in the function.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why bother min-searching? The minimizing function is a simple polynomial function of second degree in the unknown `g`, the extremum being attained when its derivative is zero, i.e.

Σk=1,2,3 [ -2 * ( (vk - c1) - g*(Dk - c2) ) * (Dk - c2)] = 0

which yields:

gm = Σk=1,2,3 [(vk - c1)*(Dk - c2)] / Σk=1,2,3 (Dk - c2)^2

If gm is negative, then you chose the first non-negative value available, which is zero:

g = max(0, gm)

*Bam!* basic math to the rescue!... :-)

The MATLAB code would be:

```
%// some test data
v  = [1,2,3];
D  = [4,5,6];
c1 = 0.3;
c2 = 0.7;

%// minimizer
g = max(0, sum((v(:)-c1).*(D(:)-c2)) / sum((D(:)-c2).^2));
```

Comment: Good idea to use basic math in this case :) Works well, thanks a lot!